# Error during initialization: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Symbol(LicencesService)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, inversifyjs

I am getting error while compiling the code : No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Symbol(LicencesService)
Following is the code associated with the issue.
The issue is with the constructor of the HTTP on server.ts file, how do I correctly inject the LicencesService?

My typings file :-

```
const TYPES = {
  LicencesService:Symbol.for('LicencesService')
}
export { TYPES }
```

My server.ts file : -

```
import { LogsRepository } from './repositories/logs'
 import { TelemetryRepository } from './repositories/telemetry'
 import { AdminRouter, AuthRouter, BotsRouter, ModulesRouter } from './routers'
 import { ContentRouter } from './routers/bots/content'
 import { ConverseRouter } from './routers/bots/converse'
 import { HintsRouter } from './routers/bots/hints'
 import { NLURouter } from './routers/bots/nlu'
 import { isDisabled } from './routers/conditionalMiddleware'
 import { InvalidExternalToken, PaymentRequiredError } from './routers/errors'
 import { SdkApiRouter } from './routers/sdk/router'
 import { ShortLinksRouter } from './routers/shortlinks'
 import { TelemetryRouter } from './routers/telemetry'
 import { hasPermissions, monitoringMiddleware, needPermissions } from './routers/util'
 import { GhostService } from './services'
 import ActionServersService from './services/action/action-servers-service'
 import ActionService from './services/action/action-service'
 import { AlertingService } from './services/alerting-service'
 import { AuthStrategies } from './services/auth-strategies'
 import AuthService, { EXTERNAL_AUTH_HEADER, SERVER_USER, TOKEN_AUDIENCE } from './services/auth/auth-service'
 import { generateUserToken } from './services/auth/util'
 import { BotService } from './services/bot-service'
 import { CMSService } from './services/cms'
 import { ConverseService } from './services/converse'
 import { FlowService } from './services/dialog/flow/service'
 import { SkillService } from './services/dialog/skill/service'
 import { HintsService } from './services/hints'
 import { JobService } from './services/job-service'
 import { LogsService } from './services/logs/service'
 import MediaService from './services/media'
 import { MonitoringService } from './services/monitoring'
 import { NLUService } from './services/nlu/nlu-service'
 import { NotificationsService } from './services/notification/service'
 import { WorkspaceService } from './services/workspace-service'
import { LicencesService } from './services/licences-service'

 import { TYPES } from './types'
 
 const BASE_API_PATH = '/api/v1'
 const SERVER_USER_STRATEGY = 'default' // The strategy isn't validated for the userver user, it could be anything.
 
 const debug = DEBUG('api')
 const debugRequest = debug.sub('request')
 
 const debugRequestMw = (req: Request, _res, next) => {
   debugRequest(`${req.path} %o`, {
     method: req.method,
     ip: req.ip,
     originalUrl: req.originalUrl
   })
 
   next()
 }
 
 @injectable()
 export default class HTTPServer {
   public httpServer!: Server
   public readonly app: express.Express
   private isBotpressReady = false
 
   private readonly authRouter: AuthRouter
   private readonly adminRouter: AdminRouter
   private readonly botsRouter: BotsRouter
   private contentRouter!: ContentRouter
   private nluRouter!: NLURouter
   private readonly modulesRouter: ModulesRouter
   private readonly shortLinksRouter: ShortLinksRouter
   private converseRouter!: ConverseRouter
   private hintsRouter!: HintsRouter
   private telemetryRouter!: TelemetryRouter
   private readonly sdkApiRouter!: SdkApiRouter
   private _needPermissions: (
     operation: string,
     resource: string
   ) => (req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>
   private _hasPermissions: (
     req: RequestWithUser,
     operation: string,
     resource: string,
     noAudit?: boolean
   ) => Promise<boolean>
   private indexCache: { [pageUrl: string]: string } = {}
 
   private jwksClient?: jwksRsa.JwksClient
   private jwksKeyId?: string
 
   constructor(
     @inject(TYPES.ConfigProvider) private configProvider: ConfigProvider,
     @inject(TYPES.Logger)
     @tagged('name', 'HTTP')
     private logger: Logger,
     @inject(TYPES.CMSService) private cmsService: CMSService,
     @inject(TYPES.FlowService) flowService: FlowService,
     @inject(TYPES.ActionService) actionService: ActionService,
     @inject(TYPES.ActionServersService) actionServersService: ActionServersService,
     @inject(TYPES.ModuleLoader) moduleLoader: ModuleLoader,
     @inject(TYPES.AuthService) private authService: AuthService,
     @inject(TYPES.MediaService) mediaService: MediaService,
     @inject(TYPES.LogsService) logsService: LogsService,
     @inject(TYPES.NotificationsService) notificationService: NotificationsService,
     @inject(TYPES.SkillService) skillService: SkillService,
     @inject(TYPES.LicencesService) private licencesService: LicencesService,
     @inject(TYPES.GhostService) private ghostService: GhostService,
     @inject(TYPES.HintsService) private hintsService: HintsService,
     @inject(TYPES.LicensingService) licenseService: LicensingService,
     @inject(TYPES.ConverseService) private converseService: ConverseService,
     @inject(TYPES.WorkspaceService) private workspaceService: WorkspaceService,
     @inject(TYPES.BotService) private botService: BotService,
     @inject(TYPES.AuthStrategies) private authStrategies: AuthStrategies,
     @inject(TYPES.MonitoringService) private monitoringService: MonitoringService,
     @inject(TYPES.AlertingService) private alertingService: AlertingService,
     @inject(TYPES.JobService) private jobService: JobService,
     @inject(TYPES.LogsRepository) private logsRepo: LogsRepository,
     @inject(TYPES.NLUService) private nluService: NLUService,
     @inject(TYPES.TelemetryRepository) private telemetryRepo: TelemetryRepository
   ) {
     this.app = express()
 
     if (!process.IS_PRODUCTION) {
       this.app.use(errorHandler())
     }
 
     if (process.core_env.REVERSE_PROXY) {
       const boolVal = yn(process.core_env.REVERSE_PROXY)
       this.app.set('trust proxy', boolVal === null ? process.core_env.REVERSE_PROXY : boolVal)
     }
 
     this.app.use(debugRequestMw)
 
     this.modulesRouter = new ModulesRouter(
       this.logger,
       this.authService,
       moduleLoader,
       skillService,
       this.configProvider
     )
 
     this.authRouter = new AuthRouter(
       this.logger,
       this.authService,
       this.configProvider,
       this.workspaceService,
       this.authStrategies
     )
     this.adminRouter = new AdminRouter(
       this.logger,
       this.authService,
       this.workspaceService,
+      this.licencesService,
       this.botService,
       licenseService,
       this.ghostService,
       this.configProvider,
       this.monitoringService,
       this.alertingService,
       moduleLoader,
       this.jobService,
       this.logsRepo
     )
     this.shortLinksRouter = new ShortLinksRouter(this.logger)
     this.botsRouter = new BotsRouter({
       actionService,
       actionServersService,
       botService,
       cmsService,
       configProvider,
       flowService,
       mediaService,
       logsService,
       notificationService,
       authService,
       ghostService,
       workspaceService,
       moduleLoader,
       logger: this.logger
     })
     this.sdkApiRouter = new SdkApiRouter(this.logger)
     this.telemetryRouter = new TelemetryRouter(this.logger, this.authService, this.telemetryRepo)
 
     this._needPermissions = needPermissions(this.workspaceService)
     this._hasPermissions = hasPermissions(this.workspaceService)
   }
 
   async setupRootPath() {
     const botpressConfig = await this.configProvider.getBotpressConfig()
     const externalUrl = process.env.EXTERNAL_URL || botpressConfig.httpServer.externalUrl
 
     if (!externalUrl) {
       process.ROOT_PATH = ''
     } else {
       const pathname = new URL(externalUrl).pathname
       process.ROOT_PATH = pathname.replace(/\/+$/, '')
     }
   }
 
   @postConstruct()
   async initialize() {
     await AppLifecycle.waitFor(AppLifecycleEvents.CONFIGURATION_LOADED)
     await this.setupRootPath()
 
     const app = express()
     app.use(process.ROOT_PATH, this.app)
     this.httpServer = createServer(app)
 
     await this.botsRouter.initialize()
     this.contentRouter = new ContentRouter(
       this.logger,
       this.authService,
       this.cmsService,
       this.workspaceService,
       this.ghostService
     )
     this.nluRouter = new NLURouter(this.logger, this.authService, this.workspaceService, this.nluService)
     this.converseRouter = new ConverseRouter(this.logger, this.converseService, this.authService, this)
     this.hintsRouter = new HintsRouter(this.logger, this.hintsService, this.authService, this.workspaceService)
     this.botsRouter.router.use('/content', this.contentRouter.router)
     this.botsRouter.router.use('/converse', this.converseRouter.router)
     this.botsRouter.router.use('/nlu', this.nluRouter.router)
 
     // tslint:disable-next-line: no-floating-promises
     AppLifecycle.waitFor(AppLifecycleEvents.BOTPRESS_READY).then(() => {
       this.isBotpressReady = true
     })
 
     this.botsRouter.router.use('/hints', this.hintsRouter.router)
   }
 
   resolveAsset = file => path.resolve(process.PROJECT_LOCATION, 'data/assets', file)
 
   async start() {
     const botpressConfig = await this.configProvider.getBotpressConfig()
     const config = botpressConfig.httpServer
     await this.sdkApiRouter.initialize()
 
     /**
      * The loading of language models can take some time, access to Botpress is disabled until it is completed
      * During this time, internal calls between modules can be made
      */
     this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
       res.removeHeader('X-Powered-By') // Removes the default X-Powered-By: Express
       res.set(config.headers)
       if (!this.isBotpressReady) {
         if (!(req.headers['user-agent'] || '').includes('axios') || !req.headers.authorization) {
           return res
             .status(503)
             .send(
               '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"> </head><body>Botpress is loading. Please try again in a minute.</body></html>'
             )
         }
       }
       next()
     })
 
     this.app.use(monitoringMiddleware)
 
     if (config.session && config.session.enabled) {
       this.app.use(
         session({
           secret: process.APP_SECRET,
           secure: true,
           httpOnly: true,
           domain: config.externalUrl,
           maxAge: ms(config.session.maxAge)
         })
       )
     }
 
     this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
       if (!isDisabled('bodyParserJson', req)) {
         bodyParser.json({ limit: config.bodyLimit })(req, res, next)
       } else {
         next()
       }
     })
 
     this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
       if (!isDisabled('bodyParserUrlEncoder', req)) {
         bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })(req, res, next)
       } else {
         next()
       }
     })
 
     if (config.cors && config.cors.enabled) {
       this.app.use(cors(config.cors.origin ? { origin: config.cors.origin } : {}))
     }
 
     this.app.get('/status', async (req, res, next) => {
       res.send(await this.monitoringService.getStatus())
     })
 
     this.app.get('/version', async (req, res) => {
       res.send(process.BOTPRESS_VERSION)
     })
 
     this.app.get('/env.js', async (req, res) => {
       const branding = await this.configProvider.getBrandingConfig('admin')
 
       res.contentType('text/javascript')
       res.send(`
       (function(window) {
           window.APP_VERSION = "${process.BOTPRESS_VERSION}";
           window.APP_NAME = "${branding.title}";
           window.APP_FAVICON = "${branding.favicon}";
           window.APP_CUSTOM_CSS = "${branding.customCss}";
           window.TELEMETRY_URL = "${process.TELEMETRY_URL}";
           window.SEND_USAGE_STATS = "${botpressConfig!.sendUsageStats}";
         })(typeof window != 'undefined' ? window : {})
       `)
     })
 
     this.app.use('/assets', this.guardWhiteLabel(), express.static(this.resolveAsset('')))
     this.app.use(rewrite('/:app/:botId/*env.js', '/api/v1/bots/:botId/:app/js/env.js'))
 
     this.app.use(`${BASE_API_PATH}/auth`, this.authRouter.router)
     this.app.use(`${BASE_API_PATH}/admin`, this.adminRouter.router)
     this.app.use(`${BASE_API_PATH}/modules`, this.modulesRouter.router)
     this.app.use(`${BASE_API_PATH}/bots/:botId`, this.botsRouter.router)
     this.app.use(`${BASE_API_PATH}/sdk`, this.sdkApiRouter.router)
     this.app.use(`${BASE_API_PATH}/telemetry`, this.telemetryRouter.router)
     this.app.use('/s', this.shortLinksRouter.router)
 
     this.app.use((err, _req, _res, next) => {
       if (err instanceof UnlicensedError) {
         next(new PaymentRequiredError(`Server is unlicensed "${err.message}"`))
       } else {
         if (err.statusCode === 413) {
           this.logger.error('You may need to increase httpServer.bodyLimit in file data/global/botpress.config.json')
         }
         next(err)
       }
     })
 
     this.app.use(function handleUnexpectedError(err, req, res, next) {
       const statusCode = err.statusCode || 400
       const errorCode = err.errorCode
       const message = err.message || err || 'Unexpected error'
       const details = err.details || ''
       const docs = err.docs || 'https://botpress.com/docs'
       const devOnly = process.IS_PRODUCTION ? {} : { showStackInDev: true, stack: err.stack, full: err.message }
 
       res.status(statusCode).json({
         statusCode,
         errorCode,
         type: err.type || Object.getPrototypeOf(err).name || 'Exception',
         message,
         details,
         docs,
         ...devOnly
       })
     })
 
     this.setupStaticRoutes(this.app)
 
     process.HOST = config.host
     process.PORT = await portFinder.getPortPromise({ port: config.port })
     process.EXTERNAL_URL = process.env.EXTERNAL_URL || config.externalUrl || `http://${process.HOST}:${process.PORT}`
     process.LOCAL_URL = `http://${process.HOST}:${process.PORT}${process.ROOT_PATH}`
 
     if (process.PORT !== config.port) {
       this.logger.warn(`Configured port ${config.port} is already in use. Using next port available: ${process.PORT}`)
     }
 
     if (!process.env.EXTERNAL_URL && !config.externalUrl) {
       this.logger.warn(
         `External URL is not configured. Using default value of ${process.EXTERNAL_URL}. Some features may not work properly`
       )
     }
 
     const hostname = config.host === 'localhost' ? undefined : config.host
     await Promise.fromCallback(callback => {
       this.httpServer.listen(process.PORT, hostname, config.backlog, callback)
     })
 
     return this.app
   }
 
   private guardWhiteLabel() {
     return (req, res, next) => {
       if (path.normalize(req.path) === '/custom-theme.css' && (!process.IS_PRO_ENABLED || !process.IS_LICENSED)) {
         return res.sendStatus(404)
       }
       next()
     }
   }
 
   setupStaticRoutes(app) {
     // Dynamically updates the static paths of index files
     const resolveIndexPaths = page => (req, res) => {
       res.contentType('text/html')
 
       // Not caching pages in dev (issue with webpack )
       if (this.indexCache[page] && process.IS_PRODUCTION) {
         return res.send(this.indexCache[page])
       }
 
       fs.readFile(this.resolveAsset(page), (err, data) => {
         if (data) {
           this.indexCache[page] = data
             .toString()
             .replace(/\<base href=\"\/\" ?\/\>/, `<base href="${process.ROOT_PATH}/" />`)
             .replace(/ROOT_PATH=""|ROOT_PATH = ''/, `window.ROOT_PATH="${process.ROOT_PATH}"`)
 
           res.send(this.indexCache[page])
         } else {
           res.sendStatus(404)
         }
       })
     }
 
     app.get('/studio', (req, res, next) => res.redirect('/admin'))
 
     app.use('/:app(studio)/:botId', express.static(this.resolveAsset('ui-studio/public'), { index: false }))
     app.use('/:app(studio)/:botId', resolveIndexPaths('ui-studio/public/index.html'))
 
     app.use('/:app(lite)/:botId?', express.static(this.resolveAsset('ui-studio/public/lite'), { index: false }))
     app.use('/:app(lite)/:botId?', resolveIndexPaths('ui-studio/public/lite/index.html'))
 
     app.use('/:app(lite)/:botId', express.static(this.resolveAsset('ui-studio/public'), { index: false }))
     app.use('/:app(lite)/:botId', resolveIndexPaths('ui-studio/public/index.html'))
 
     app.get(['/:app(studio)/:botId/*'], resolveIndexPaths('ui-studio/public/index.html'))
 
     app.use('/admin', express.static(this.resolveAsset('ui-admin/public'), { index: false }))
     app.get(['/admin', '/admin/*'], resolveIndexPaths('ui-admin/public/index.html'))
 
     app.get('/', (req, res) => res.redirect(`${process.ROOT_PATH}/admin`))
   }
 
   createRouterForBot(router: string, identity: string, options: RouterOptions): any & http.RouterExtension {
     return this.botsRouter.getNewRouter(router, identity, options)
   }
 
   needPermission(operation: string, resource: string) {
     return this._needPermissions(operation, resource)
   }
 
   hasPermission(req: RequestWithUser, operation: string, resource: string, noAudit?: boolean) {
     return this._hasPermissions(req, operation, resource, noAudit)
   }
 
   deleteRouterForBot(router: string): void {
     return this.botsRouter.deleteRouter(router, this.app)
   }
 
   createShortLink(name: string, destination: string, params: any) {
     this.shortLinksRouter.createShortLink(name, destination, params)
   }
 
   deleteShortLink(name: string) {
     this.shortLinksRouter.deleteShortLink(name)
   }
 
   async getAxiosConfigForBot(botId: string, options?: AxiosOptions): Promise<AxiosBotConfig> {
     const basePath = options && options.localUrl ? process.LOCAL_URL : process.EXTERNAL_URL
     const serverToken = generateUserToken(SERVER_USER, SERVER_USER_STRATEGY, false, '5m', TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
     return {
       baseURL: `${basePath}/api/v1/bots/${botId}`,
       headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${serverToken}`
       }
     }
   }
 
   extractExternalToken = async (req, res, next) => {
     if (req.headers[EXTERNAL_AUTH_HEADER]) {
       try {
         req.credentials = await this.decodeExternalToken(req.headers[EXTERNAL_AUTH_HEADER])
       } catch (error) {
         return next(new InvalidExternalToken(error.message))
       }
     }
 
     next()
   }
 
   async decodeExternalToken(externalToken): Promise<any | undefined> {
     const externalAuth = await this._getExternalAuthConfig()
 
     if (!externalAuth || !externalAuth.enabled) {
       return
     }
 
     const { audience, algorithms, issuer } = externalAuth
     let publicKey = externalAuth.publicKey
 
     if (this.jwksClient && this.jwksKeyId) {
       try {
         const key = await Promise.fromCallback<jwksRsa.SigningKey>(cb =>
           this.jwksClient!.getSigningKey(this.jwksKeyId!, cb)
         )
         publicKey = key.getPublicKey()
       } catch (err) {
         return new Error(`There was an error while trying to fetch the jwks keys. ${err}`)
       }
     }
 
     const [scheme, token] = externalToken.split(' ')
     if (scheme.toLowerCase() !== 'bearer') {
       return new Error(`Unknown scheme "${scheme}"`)
     }
 
     return Promise.fromCallback(cb => {
       jsonwebtoken.verify(token, publicKey!, { issuer, audience, algorithms }, (err, user) => {
         cb(err, !err ? user : undefined)
       })
     })
   }
 
   @Memoize()
   private async _getExternalAuthConfig(): Promise<ExternalAuthConfig | undefined> {
     const botpressConfig = await this.configProvider.getBotpressConfig()
     const config = botpressConfig.pro.externalAuth
 
     if (!config || !config.enabled) {
       return
     }
 
     if (config.jwksClient) {
       const { keyId, jwksUri } = config.jwksClient
 
       if (!keyId || !jwksUri) {
         this.logger.error(
           "External User Auth: Couldn't configure the JWKS Client. They keyId and jwksUri parameters must be set"
         )
         return
       }
 
       this.jwksClient = jwksRsa(config.jwksClient)
       this.jwksKeyId = config.jwksClient.keyId
     } else if (!config.publicKey) {
       try {
         config.publicKey = await this.ghostService.global().readFileAsString('/', 'end_users_auth.pub')
       } catch (error) {
         this.logger
           .attachError(error)
           .error("External User Auth: Couldn't open public key file /data/global/end_users_auth.pub")
         return
       }
     } else if (config.publicKey.length < 128) {
       this.logger.error('External User Auth: The provided publicKey is invalid (too short). Min length is 128 chars.')
       return
     }
 
     return config
   }
 }
```

My Licences Service : -

```
import { inject, injectable, tagged } from 'inversify'
import {LicencesRepository} from 'core/repositories/licences_repositories'
import {Logger} from 'botpress/sdk'

import { TYPES } from '../types'

@injectable()
export declare class LicencesService {
  constructor(
    //@inject(TYPES.Logger)
    //@tagged('name', 'LicencesService')
    /* private */ logger: Logger,
    //@inject(TYPES.Licences) 
    /* private */ licences: LicencesRepository
    
  )
   getLicences() /* {
  return this.licences.getLicences();
} */

}
export {};
```

My Bindings : -

```
import LicensingService from 'common/licensing-service'
import { DialogContainerModule } from 'core/services/dialog/dialog.inversify'
import { CEJobService, JobService } from 'core/services/job-service'
import { ContainerModule, interfaces } from 'inversify'

import { TYPES } from '../types'

import ActionServersService from './action/action-servers-service'
import ActionService from './action/action-service'
import { AlertingService, CEAlertingService } from './alerting-service'
import { AuthStrategies, CEAuthStrategies } from './auth-strategies'
import AuthService from './auth/auth-service'
import { BotMonitoringService } from './bot-monitoring-service'
import { BotService } from './bot-service'
import { CMSService } from './cms'
import { ConverseService } from './converse'
import { SkillService } from './dialog/skill/service'
import { GhostContainerModule } from './ghost/ghost.inversify'
import { HintsService } from './hints'
import { HookService } from './hook/hook-service'
import { KeyValueStore } from './kvs'
import CELicensingService from './licensing'
import { LogsJanitor } from './logs/janitor'
import { LogsService } from './logs/service'
import MediaService from './media'
import { EventEngine } from './middleware/event-engine'
import { CEMonitoringService, MonitoringService } from './monitoring'
import { NLUService } from './nlu/nlu-service'
import { NotificationsService } from './notification/service'
import { Queue } from './queue'
import MemoryQueue from './queue/memory-queue'
import RealtimeService from './realtime'
import { StatsService } from './stats-service'

const ServicesContainerModule = new ContainerModule((bind: interfaces.Bind) => {
  bind<CMSService>(TYPES.CMSService)
    .to(CMSService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<NLUService>(TYPES.NLUService)
    .to(NLUService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<MediaService>(TYPES.MediaService)
    .to(MediaService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<ActionService>(TYPES.ActionService)
    .to(ActionService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<ActionServersService>(TYPES.ActionServersService)
    .to(ActionServersService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<LicensingService>(TYPES.LicensingService)
    .to(CELicensingService)
    .inSingletonScope()
    .when(() => !process.IS_PRO_ENABLED)

  bind<JobService>(TYPES.JobService)
    .to(CEJobService)
    .inSingletonScope()
    .when(() => !process.IS_PRODUCTION || !process.CLUSTER_ENABLED || !process.IS_PRO_ENABLED)

  bind<MonitoringService>(TYPES.MonitoringService)
    .to(CEMonitoringService)
    .inSingletonScope()
    .when(() => !process.CLUSTER_ENABLED || !process.IS_PRO_ENABLED)

  bind<AlertingService>(TYPES.AlertingService)
    .to(CEAlertingService)
    .inSingletonScope()
    .when(() => !process.CLUSTER_ENABLED || !process.IS_PRO_ENABLED)

  bind<BotMonitoringService>(TYPES.BotMonitoringService)
    .to(BotMonitoringService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<AuthStrategies>(TYPES.AuthStrategies)
    .to(CEAuthStrategies)
    .inSingletonScope()
    .when(() => !process.IS_PRO_ENABLED)

  bind<Queue>(TYPES.IncomingQueue).toDynamicValue((context: interfaces.Context) => {
    return new MemoryQueue('Incoming', context.container.getTagged(TYPES.Logger, 'name', 'IQueue'))
  })

  bind<Queue>(TYPES.OutgoingQueue).toDynamicValue((context: interfaces.Context) => {
    return new MemoryQueue('Outgoing', context.container.getTagged(TYPES.Logger, 'name', 'OQueue'))
  })

  bind<HookService>(TYPES.HookService)
    .to(HookService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<HintsService>(TYPES.HintsService)
    .to(HintsService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<EventEngine>(TYPES.EventEngine)
    .to(EventEngine)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<RealtimeService>(TYPES.RealtimeService)
    .to(RealtimeService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<AuthService>(TYPES.AuthService)
    .to(AuthService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<LogsJanitor>(TYPES.LogJanitorRunner)
    .to(LogsJanitor)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<LogsService>(TYPES.LogsService)
    .to(LogsService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<NotificationsService>(TYPES.NotificationsService)
    .to(NotificationsService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<KeyValueStore>(TYPES.KeyValueStore)
    .to(KeyValueStore)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<SkillService>(TYPES.SkillService)
    .to(SkillService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<ConverseService>(TYPES.ConverseService)
    .to(ConverseService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<BotService>(TYPES.BotService)
    .to(BotService)
    .inSingletonScope()

  bind<StatsService>(TYPES.StatsService)
    .to(StatsService)
    .inSingletonScope()


})

export const ServicesContainerModules = [ServicesContainerModule, DialogContainerModule, GhostContainerModule]
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution, I needed to add in bindings : -

import this : -

```
import { LicencesService } from './licences-service'
```

Add binding like this in ServicesContainerModule : -

```
bind<LicencesService>(TYPES.LicencesService)
        .to(LicencesService)
        .inSingletonScope()
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due you are not binging some symbol, or you are bingind twice the same.

My case was

`bind<SessionService>(coreTypes.services.SessionService).to(SessionServiceImpl); bind<AuthService> (coreTypes.services.SessionService).to(AuthServiceImpl);`

After correct my mistake all was solved